# Create byte literals in scala using implicits

Tags: scala, implicit

I am trying to create a byte literal in scala using the implicit classes. But, I am finding it hard to understand why this does not work

here fixed.get() returns Byte

```
implicit class ByteContext(private val sc: StringContext) {
      def hex(args: Any*): Byte = {
        val parts = sc.parts.toList
        assert(
          parts.size == 1 && args.size == 0,
          "Expected a string literal with exactly one part"
        )
        Integer.parseInt(parts(0), 16).toByte
      }
    }

    val aByte = hex"0x4D"
    if ((fixed.get() ne aByte) || (fixed.get() ne aByte)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Magic of ciphertext number doesn't match")
```

Here is the error I am getting

```
Error:(49, 25) the result type of an implicit conversion must be more specific than AnyRef
    if ((fixed.get() ne aByte) || (fixed.get() ne aByte)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Magic of ciphertext number doesn't match")
Error:(49, 25) type mismatch;
 found   : Byte
 required: AnyRef
    if ((fixed.get() ne aByte) || (fixed.get() ne aByte)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Magic of ciphertext number doesn't match")
Error:(49, 51) the result type of an implicit conversion must be more specific than AnyRef
    if ((fixed.get() ne aByte) || (fixed.get() ne aByte)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Magic of ciphertext number doesn't match")
Error:(49, 51) type mismatch;
 found   : Byte
 required: AnyRef
    if ((fixed.get() ne aByte) || (fixed.get() ne aByte)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Magic of ciphertext number doesn't match")
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is not about the `ByteContext` implicit conversion.

```
42 ne 43  
//Error: the result type of an implicit conversion must be more specific than AnyRef
```

`ne` is a method in the `AnyRef` class, used to test whether A is/is-not a reference to B. But your `Byte` values are not references. The compiler is telling you that converting them to the expected type, `AnyRef`, isn't allowed.

BTW, `java.lang.Byte.valueOf(parts(0),16)` is probably a more direct `String` to `Byte` conversion.